# Incorrect Class Member Offset Address

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, compilation

I have an issue where when I try to access a member of a class in a certain file, it does not get the actual value of that member. But when I try to access it in other places I do.

File A:

```
find_func_wrapper ( Func_Container * rules, char * func_name ) {
    ulong count = rules->function_count;
    cout << "A count: " << count << endl;
    B::find_func( rules, func_name );
}

main () {
    Func_Container *rules = get_rules();
    find_func_wrapper( rules, func_name );
}
```

File B:

```
B::find_func ( Func_Container * rules, char * func_name ) {
    ulong count = rules->function_count;
    cout << "B count: " << count << endl;
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
A count: 2
B count: 0
```

When the count member is set to 2. Stepping through the code with gdb, in both A and B when I use `print rules->function_count` I get 2.

Disassembling the code, in A find_func_wrapper.

```
1885            ulong count = rules->function_count;
=> 0x0000000006004be5 <+294>:   mov    -0xa8(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000006004bec <+301>:   mov    0x60a8(%rax),%rax
   0x0000000006004bf3 <+308>:   mov    %rax,-0x38(%rbp)
```

Also `print &rules->function_count = 0x11684158` and `print rules = 0x1167e0b0` 
And in B::find_func

```
2652        ulong count = rules->function_count;
   0x00000000062494a1 <+75>:    mov    -0x4f8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000062494a8 <+82>:    mov    0x60e8(%rax),%rax
   0x00000000062494af <+89>:    mov    %rax,-0x50(%rbp)
```

Printing the addresses of rules and ->function_count return the same addresses as expected. To me, it looks like the culprit is in the second `mov` instruction where the offset used in B, 0x60e8, is incorrect. Why would this be happening?

get_rules() returns a pointer to a global object that is initialized earlier and kept around till the program ends.

This is being compiled with gcc 4.4.7. The project is extremely large. Additionally, this only happens in debug builds, release builds or non-optimized builds don't seem to have this issue.

```
Sizeof in find_func_wrapper: 24968
    Offset: 3093
Sizeof in B::find_func: 25032
    Offset: 3101
```

Offset calculated by `((&rules->function_count) - rules)`

Comment: This sounds like it has to do with alignment. Usually when you store a class to a file you specify the alignment before the header. In visual studio that'd be something like #pragma pack(1)

Comment: Make sure both TUs are sharing the same definition of `Func_Container` and do a clean and rebuild. Visual Studio screws up and forgets to recompile object files sometimes.

Comment: Are you sure both files are compiled with the same flags? This sounds like func_container might have optional ifdef'd fields. Print sizeof(func_container) in both functions.

Comment: This is a clean build, Also, there is no use of pragma pack that I can find in the project.

Comment: What's in the corresponding headers?

Comment: @Frob I've updated the question with sizeof() and offset information.
The headers are huge, I'll look for anything that might be caused by ifdefs, is there anything else I should look for.

Comment: That's not the correct way to calculate an offset. You should use `offsetof`.`

Comment: @EJP I couldn't get offsetof to work on this class.

Comment: After rearranging some thing I did find out that it seems to be because of _GLIBCXX_DEBUG. The first included header in B defines this. If I include my header for Func_Container it works correctly. I don't immediately see anything in the definition for Func_Container that is #ifdef'd to depend on this value but I don't know what it causes the compiler to do.

Comment: Please add your last comment as an answer with a little more detail, pay it forward to the next person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to narrow down the source of my issue be rearranging header includes. After placing the `#include "Func_Container.h"` before other includes in file B, I found that the container became the correct size. I proceeded to move other headers before `Func_Container` until I found which one was causing the issue. I found that the offending header had the `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag defined. This caused extra debug members in certain std types which changed their sizes, so when my definition for Func_Container was loaded in later member addresses changed as a result of the larger types.

An example of the issue is available in this mailing list: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-10/msg00077.html